# Truck restrictions not respected - wrong calculated route for truck

Tags: here-api, restriction

After many tests on HERE API examples, I have problem with calculating proper route respecting truck restrictions. The restrictions are not respected and route goes through them.

Here provides page where I perform tests (one of many similar):
https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3/fleet_telematics_api

I use "Expert Mode" since I'd like to provide URL from documentation which doesn't respect "t" and "m" letters in length/weight parameters.
My URL for example has following parameters (please replace app_id and app_code:

https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?&routeattributes=wp,sm,sh,lg,no,ri,sc&waypoint0=52.988239,19.033636&waypoint1=52.226306,19.600028&mode=fastest;truck;traffic:disabled;tollroad:-3&driver_cost=0&vehicle_cost=3.5&alternatives=4&weightPerAxle=12&limitedWeight=40&height=4&width=2.55&length=16.5&trailersCount=1&legattributes=li&jsonattributes=41&linkattributes=rd,tr&app_id=XXXXXXXXXX&app_code=YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY

As you can see, the route has 2 alternative calculations. Unfortunately, both of them violate truck restrictions at very beginning of route. I provide screenshot with details:

https://mobitum.com/route-description.png

and map without track to visualise restrictions:

https://mobitum.com/route-no-track.png

Am I doing something wrong or my parameters are misplaced?
I'm just expecting properly calculated route for truck with restrictions respected ;-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no weight limitation on the motorway that the route takes.
and the request which you are parsing is following the motorway route.

[image]

It looks like the router is on the motorway while the weight restriction is on a minor road that over/underpasses the motorway.

Hope this helps!

Comment: My route is NOT following the motorway route. Did you check **API URL** I send within question ? **Remember to paste it into textarea in Expert mode**.
The API params indicate to avoid motorway/tollroad: mode=fastest;truck;traffic:disabled;**tollroad:-3**

Comment: @Maciej: the investigation is ongoing, we will keep you informed.

Answer (score 0):

@HERE Developer Support - seems like you don't read carefully my question and haven't looked at screens I attached. **My route is NOT following the motorway route.**